# How to return a unique record

Tags: sql

I have an SQL scenario where I want to return records 2 weeks or older from a table, but only if there aren't other records more recent with the same join. Here are the two tables:

PRIMARY TABLE:

```
ID | SECONDARYID | CREATION_DATE | DESCRIPTION
---------------------------------------------------
```

SECONDARY TABLE:

```
ID | NAME | PHONE_NUMBER ....
---------------------------------------------------
```

The primary table has the following records:

```
ID | SECONDARYID  | CREATION_DATE | DESCRIPTION
---------------------------------------------------
3  | 305          | 2022-01-14    | some other description
2  | 300          | 2022-01-10    | some 2nd description
1  | 300          | 2022-01-01    | some description
```

So far I have the following query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM PRIMARY
JOIN SECONDARY ON PRIMARY.SECONDARYID = SECONDARY.ID
WHERE PRIMARY.CREATIONDATE BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND NOW()
```

It returns the record from the primary table with an ID of 1. However, I want to update this query so that it doesn't return that record since there is a newer entry with the same secondaryid that isn't older than 2 weeks. Please assist.

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL; what are you really using? The above, however, is *not* valid T-SQL, so that suggests the latter, or you have been reading the wrong documentation for the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Assume this is all pseudocode and that the end where I query for the two week interval does what it's supposed to.

Comment: That doesn't answer what RDBMS you're *really* using.

Comment: I'm trying to edit an advanced query on Outsystems.

Comment: Who use what RDBMS...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can inner join to a table with max `creation_date` per `secondaryid` to ensure you have only latest `creation_date`

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM PRIMARY
JOIN SECONDARY ON PRIMARY.SECONDARYID = SECONDARY.ID
inner join (
  select 
  secondaryid
  , max(creationdate) maxdate 
  from PRIMARY 
  group by secondaryid) mx 
on PRIMARY.seconardyid = mx.secondaryid and mx.maxdate = PRIMARY.creationdate 
WHERE PRIMARY.CREATIONDATE BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND NOW()
```